# First Proth number with a million digits

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am examining the Proth numbers $n = h\cdot 2^k+1$, where $k$ is an integer and $h<2^k$ an odd integer.
Now I want to find the first Proth number with a million digits.
But I hve no idea how I could solve this.
So I know that we get the number of digits of $n$ by $\lfloor \log_{10}(n)\rfloor + 1$.
So I write
$$
\log_{10}(n) 
= \log_{10}(h\cdot 2^k+1)\approx \log_{10}(h) + k\cdot\log_{10}(2).
$$
But how would I go on from here?

Answer (score 1):

The binary expansion of $n=h\cdot 2^k+1$ looks like this:

$$\underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{\le k \text{ digits}}\;\;\;\;\underbrace{0\ldots0}_{k-1\;0's}1$$

So you take the binary expansion of $10^{999,999}$, and look for the least significant zero digit that is no more than half-way from the start; then replace this digit by $1$, replace all less-significant digits with $0$, and add $1$.

Comment: shouldn't there be an $h$ in the binary expansion, too?

Comment: @Lereu: $h$ is the number defined by those initial $\le k$ digits.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for clarification. Yet i have problems to get to the solution. I don't really understand what to do now.

Comment: To make it a bit clearer, let's try $3$ digits instead of a million.  $10^2 =1100100$ in binary.  This is $7$ bits: the third one  happens to be $0$, so we replace that by $1$, replace the less-significant digits by $0$, and then add $1$, obtaining $1110001$ in binary or $113$ in decimal, i.e. $113 =  7 \cdot 2^4 + 1$ is the first Proth number with $3$ decimal digits.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you, I understand that. But if I try it with 4 digits, I have $10^3 = 1111101000_2$, so there is no 0 half-way from the start. What do i do?

Comment: @Lereu: A good question! In this special case, you have to add a leading $0$, and that becomes the least significant zero digit. So you get $1111101000_2\to 01111101000_2\to 10000000001_2=1025$, with $h=1$ and $k=10$.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you, but I guess the formula is wrong, e.g. $10^5 = 11000011010100000_2$. So this becomes to $11100000000000001_2 = 114689$. But the first Proth number with 6 digits is $100865$.

Comment: No, the _least_ significant zero digit that is no more than half-way from the start is in the sixth place:
$$11000\color{red}{0}11010100000_2\to 11000\color{red}{1}00000000001_2=100353$$

Which looks like a Proth number to me!